# Get the max date from each ROW

Tags: postgresql, row, maxdate

I have this table:

[image]

How can I get the MAX date for each ID from each row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **[Greatest](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-conditional.html)**

```
 SELECT id, GREATEST (date1, date2, date3)
 FROM YourTable
```

> Note that GREATEST and LEAST are not in the SQL standard, but are a common extension. Some other databases make them return NULL if any argument is NULL, rather than only when all are NULL.

Comment: Didn't know about the function! Thank you so much.